# modify passwords of 3 users of one database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try modifying users passwords of one SQL database but find no way to do that.
The SQL server is 2008 and a database, for example, named as 'factory' is created months ago. There are several users under this database, such as 'grpleader', 'prjleader' and 'teamhead' for examples. These three users are mapped to 'sa'. 
What I wanna doing is to modify an .asp connection code given below

```
    strConn = "Provider=sqloledb; User ID=grpleader; Password=r_32_Dosu_sz_qzyp; Initial Catalog=factory; Data Source=202.204.251.30,1433"
    strConn1 ="Provider=sqloledb; User ID=prjleader; Password=Oi_jcvx_876_pgy_erl; Initial Catalog=factory; Data Source=202.204.251.30,1433"
    strConn2 ="Provider=sqloledb; User ID=teamhead; Password=eqjJ_Ui9_tjqw_l5; Initial Catalog=factory; Data Source=202.204.251.30,1433"
```

It seems that each of these users has a password in initial and I just want to give them a new password but failed to do it after attempts many times.

Comment: you need to change login password,i dont see anything but connection string in your code

Comment: User ID=grpleader; Password=r_32_Dosu_sz_qzyp; 
I found this kind of thing in global.asa file. Doesn't that mean the password and user-id required when visiting the database.

Comment: It's for the login

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: cannot open that link